# Primeng Menu on dialog

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm struggling with the issue. If you have not popup menu on dialog, and close the dialog, when you reopen it, menu does not appear

```
<p-dialog modal="true" appendTo="body" [contentStyle]="{width: '800px', height: '650px' }" [(visible)]="projectManager">
  <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;">
    <img src="./assets/images/qubix32.png" style="display: inline">
    <span style="font-size: 20px">       Welcome </span>
  </div>
  <div class="p-grid" >
    <div class="p-col-fixed" style="width:150px">
      <span>work</span>
      <p-menu [model]="main"></p-menu>
    </div>

    <div class="p-col">

      <h3 style="margin-bottom: 10px"> Recent projects </h3>
     <div style="margin-bottom: 4px"  *ngFor="let program of this.programs">
       <a href="#" [ngStyle]="{'font-size':'12px'}"[title]="program.value" ><br/><u>{{program.label}}</u></a>
       <span [ngStyle]="{'font-size':'10px', 'font-color': 'gray'}"> <br/>  {{program.value}}</span>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="p-col"  class="p-col-fixed" style="width:140px">
      <span>work</span>
      <p-menu [ngStyle]="{'float': 'right'}" [model]="info"></p-menu>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3 style="margin-top: 20px"> Your Repo </h3>
    <p-tree [contextMenu]="cm"  [value]="files1" selectionMode="multiple" [draggableNodes]="true" [droppableNodes]="true" draggableScope="self" droppableScope="self" [filter]="true" [style]="{'margin-top':'10px', 'width': '100%', 'height': '200px','max-height':'268px','overflow':'auto'}"></p-tree>
  </div>
  <p-contextMenu #cm appendTo="body" [model]="contextMenu"></p-contextMenu>
</p-dialog>
```

No other manipulation from code are present.
Analyzing generated styles I realized that something set opacity of menu to 0. How can it be overcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the way to overcome it(rude way) is to manualy set opacity to element, when dialog got show event.
Here I add onShow event handler.

```
<p-dialog (onShow)="reinit($event)" modal="true" appendTo="body" [contentStyle]="{width: '800px', height: '650px' }" [(visible)]="projectManager">
```

In reinit function:

```
 reinit($event: any) {
   let element = document.getElementById("menu-dialog");
   let menu = element.children[0];
   menu.setAttribute("style","opacity:1!important");
   console.log(menu);
 }
```

For primeng menu you have a structure from container div (p-menu div). The issue is that opacity=0 is set to child div. So, we get this div as a 0 child (the only child p-menu div has, so no magic numbers here), and just set opacity to 0.